# Http request boundaries getting caught in pdf decoding process

Tags: python, http, http-headers, apigee

I'm trying to decode a base64 pdf file and send it to another endpoint.
I used a python policy for the decoding part and here's the code

```
import base64


pdfB64 = flow.getVariable("request.content")

pdfFile = base64.b64decode(pdfB64)
flow.setVariable("pdfFileDecoded",pdfFile)
```

Now, when I send my http post request which is below

```
headers :
Accept : */*
boundary : --Boundaryy

--Boundaryy
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="testdu12janvier"; filename="testdu12janvier.pdf"

Content-Type: application/pdf

<< Heres is sensitive data which is basically a base64 encoded pdf file >>

--Boundaryy--
```

When I send this POST request and trace it in Apigee Edge, I notice that something else is encoded before the pdf file I think its either the boundary or one of the headers. This makes a corrupt pdf file which can't be read.

How do I isolate the pdf file from the request body without removing boundaries? as I'll need to send multiple in near future.

Comment: I tried this but in response I keep getting a error 415 unsupported media type. Even though I passed content-type : application/pdf in the headers

Comment: There's also the fact I wanna assign a filename to this pdf which I can't do unless its in a form-data

Comment: I can try octet-stream, maybe that'll work.

Comment: Nothing worked, I tried multiple solution I either get an error 422 or 415, I tried transforming the body of the request into a json and isolate each variable, which worked ( I could see each variable on its own, name, filename and file) but it keeps sending back error 415.